# Inseting face makes model weird

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling something in blender, I want to inset a face properly but it is getting glitchy when I insert the face, tried deleting the face and grid filling it, I also tried quad and voxel remesh to retopologize but remesh makes my model weird.

[image]

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WlazeDcTEUmc3MBfHtctnLgjv9HYaChY/view?usp=sharing)

Does anyone know how to fix this or knows a different technique to make faces inset.

Answer (score 2):

The faces overlap when you inset because of your current topology. You can try that:

You have overlapping vertices, so first select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Fill the face with <kbd>F</kbd>. Select each side notche and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* in order to remove some useless vertices, in the *Operator* box choose a value around 3:

[image]

Now select all and inset:

[image]

You have overlapping faces, you just need to move some vertices to fix that, or simply merge them:

[image]

You can also correct the topology with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's really nice how you explained your answer.